# How to merge properties of two objects in Java? (properties of user defined class and keys values of Map)

Tags: java, data-structures

I am working on spring boot application and have two objects one if List of custom class and another is Map of String keys and String values. 
Ex.

```
DTO object with fixed fields fieldA,fieldB,fieldc. 

[{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val2","fieldc":"val3"},
{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val5","fieldc":"val6"}
{"fieldA": "lookupval2","fieldB": "val8","fieldc":"val9"}]
```

*additionally note this field A has duplicate values for for first two objects*

And then I have Map of Map `Map<String,Map<String,String>` like below

```
{
    lookupval1= {fieldA:"lookupval1",fieldD:"xxx",.............},
    lookupval2= {fieldA:"lookupval2",fieldD:"yyy",.............}.
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What I want is, I want to combine fields in each item of list with fields of Map, I can find the corresponding key in map by getting lookup value of fieldA.

**fieldA : lookupval1**

And then I want to send that response to the REST client, what would be the efficient method and data structure to do this?

**Expected Result:**

```
[
{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val2","fieldc":"val3",fieldD:"xxx"},
{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val2","fieldc":"val3",fieldD:"xxx"}
{"fieldA": "lookupval2","fieldB": "val8","fieldc":"val9",fieldD:"yyy"}]
]
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is the structure of DTO object and exact type of Map.

```
class DTO {
    int id;
    String name;
    String desc;
}

List<DTO> dtoList = getDTOList(); // returns list of DTO object

Map<String,Map<String,String> mapCollection
    = getMapCollection(); // return String, Map<String,String> pairs
```

- here key in mapCollection is always equal to id of DTO and DTO list
  will have duplicate values.

I have posted answer the way I have done it, but looking for better alternatives to reduce computations.

Comment: I can't understand the requirements, can you write the full expected Map? Also your input JSON does not seem right, you are missing quotes

Comment: @Bentaye, I have updated question , first is not a JSON its representation of my DTO object, I have updated the question with expected result

Comment: I think the output should be `[
{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val2","fieldc":"val3",fieldD:"xxx"},
{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val5","fieldc":"val6",fieldD:"xxx"}
{"fieldA": "lookupval2","fieldB": "val8","fieldc":"val9",fieldD:"yyy"}]
]`

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please share the complete input and output. It is not clear what you need

Comment: I was able to get what I want but that seems very explicit and will take more time when number of items are increased. 

1. created list of map List<Map<String,String>> 
2. iterated over the list of DTO object (1st object) 
3. create new map object, say singleRes 
4. added all fields of each DTO object in singleRes 
5. iterated over (2nd object) which is Map of Map 
6. lookup map by fieldA
7. Iterate over each entry and add each entry in singleRes
8. Added singleRes in list

Comment: Since I can not post code due to organization policy I will create a sample problem and will post in the question.

Comment: @AkshayNaik Are you sure about the second line of your expected output? shouldn't it be `{"fieldA": "lookupval1","fieldB": "val5","fieldc":"val6",fieldD:"xxx"}`?

Comment: @Bentaye, No since second object is Map<String,Map<String,String>> and I am  doing lookup by fieldA, expected output in question is correct.
I have updated question for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<DTO> dtoList = getDTOList(); // returns list of DTO object

Map<String,Map<String,String> mapCollection
    = getMapCollection(); // return String, Map<String,String> pairs
List<Map<String,String>> result =  new HashMap<>();

// iterate over dto list
for(DTO singleDTO : dtoList) {
    Map<String,String> singleResult = new HashMap<>();

    // Add all fields in map
    singleResult.put("id",singleDTO.getId());
    singleResult.put("name",singleDTO.getName());
    singleResult.put("desc",singleDTO.getDesc());

    // fetch single map by id lookup
    Map<String,Strig> singleMap = mapCollection.get(singleDTO.getId());
    // fetch all entries from map
    Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> entrySet = singleMap.entrySet();
   // add them in hashmap
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> singleEntry : entrySet) {
        singleResult.put(singleEntry.getKey(),singleEntry.getValue());

    Add map in the list
    result.add(singleEntry);
}}

//result

 [
    {
        "id":"1", "name":"abc", "desc":"some desc abc", "ID":"1", "mapField1":"field1 value",  "mapField2":"field1 value"
    },
    {
        "id":"1", "name":"xyz", "desc":"some desc xyz", "ID":"1", "mapField1":"field1 value",  "mapField2":"field1 value"
    },
    {
        "id":"2", "name":"pqr", "desc":"some desc pqr", "ID":"2", "mapField1":"field1 value 2",  "mapField2":"field1 value2"
    }     
 ]
```

Comment: This does not compile. `singleEntry` is undefined, also this is even more confusing we have an `int` now which is nowhere in your map. You need to make a simple input output example where you explain where everything goes.

Comment: I have updated code, this is off course not runnable code, but example to give you understanding what exactly I am doing. since problem is logical than syntactical I have not verified execution

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

Assuming your initial objects are of type `Item` as described bellow.

```
class Item {
    String fieldA,fieldB,fieldC;

    // Getters / Setter
}
```

Assuming that your initial list of `Item` is called `items`

Assuming that your initial map is called `map` and is of type `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`

**Solution**

Add a method to your Item class to return a `Map<String, String>` representation of the object

```
public Map<String, String> toMap() {
    return new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("fieldA", fieldA);
        put("fieldB", fieldB);
        put("fieldC", fieldC);
    }};
}
```

Create a method to get the `fieldD` value for a given `fieldA` value

```
private String getFieldDValueForFieldAValue(String fieldAValue) {
    return map.get(fieldAValue).get("fieldD");
}
```

Create a method to add the correct `fieldD` value to an item map

```
private Map<String, String> addFieldD(Map<String, String> itemMap) {
    itemMap.put("fieldD", getFieldDValueForFieldAValue(itemMap.get("fieldA")));
    return itemMap;
}
```

Then you can generate a list of maps for each objects with the correct `fieldD` value

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = items.stream()
    .map(Item::toMap) // Converts all Items to Maps
    .map(m -> addFieldD(m)) // Adds the correct fieldD value to each Map
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // make it a List
```

And finally make a JSON string out of it:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list, listType);
System.out.println(json);
```

This outputs the following JSON:

```
[
  {"fieldA":"lookupval1","fieldC":"val3","fieldB":"val2","fieldD":"xxx"},
  {"fieldA":"lookupval1","fieldC":"val6","fieldB":"val5","fieldD":"xxx"},
  {"fieldA":"lookupval2","fieldC":"val9","fieldB":"val8","fieldD":"yyy"}
]
```

Comment: the second object is Map<String, Map<String,String>> I have added mode details is description and added answer as well, see if you can help to improve.

Comment: in my example, the map is a `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`

Comment: oh I completely missed that, although I liked the idea of adding  helper method in the DTO object to return map, but in your code you are adding only fieldD and as I mentioned in the question map can have n number of fields. Also it has additional dependency. Can you check my answer and suggest any improvements. meanwhile I will try your code to compare performance.